# Visual Basic : Is there a WAY to shorten this raw codes

Tags: vb.net

I designed some software to help sellers for calculating the products bought by the costumer.
I coded it too raw, I know this code can be shortened but I don't know what to do.

And this is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Strg1, Strg2, Strg3, Strg4, Strg5, Strg6, Strg7, Strg8, Strg9, Strg10, Strg11, Strg12, Strg13, Strg14, Strg15, Strg16, Strg17, Strg18, Strg19, Strg20, Strg21, Strg22, Strg23, Strg24, Strg25, Strg26, Strg27, Strg28, Strg29, Strg30 As Double
Private p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16, p17, p18, p19, p20, p21, p22, p23, p24, p25, p26, p27, p28, p29, p30, MedPrc1, MedPrc2, TotMedPrc As Double
Private Function QntCalc(ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double) As Double
    Return x * y
End Function
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sder As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MedPrc1 = 0
    MedPrc2 = 0
    TotMedPrc = 0
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox1.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox1.Enabled = True
        p1 = Val(Label1.Text)
    Else
        TextBox1.Enabled = False
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        p1 = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox2.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox2.Enabled = True
        p2 = Val(Label2.Text)
    Else
        TextBox2.Enabled = False
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        p2 = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox3.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox3.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox3.Enabled = True
        p3 = Val(Label3.Text)
    Else
        TextBox3.Enabled = False
        TextBox3.Text = ""
        p3 = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox4_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox4.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox4.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox4.Enabled = True
        p4 = Val(Label4.Text)
    Else
        TextBox4.Enabled = False
        TextBox4.Text = ""
        p4 = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox5_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox5.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox5.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox5.Enabled = True
        p5 = Val(Label5.Text)
    Else
        TextBox5.Enabled = False
        TextBox5.Text = ""
        p5 = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox6_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox6.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox6.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox6.Enabled = True
        p6 = Val(Label6.Text)
    Else
        TextBox6.Enabled = False
        TextBox6.Text = ""
        p6 = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox7_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox7.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox7.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox7.Enabled = True
        p7 = Val(Label7.Text)
    Else
        TextBox7.Enabled = False
        TextBox7.Text = ""
        p7 = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox8_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox8.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox8.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox8.Enabled = True
        p8 = Val(Label8.Text)
    Else
        TextBox8.Enabled = False
        TextBox8.Text = ""
        p8 = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox9_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox9.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox9.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox9.Enabled = True
        p9 = Val(Label9.Text)
    Else
        TextBox9.Enabled = False
        TextBox9.Text = ""
        p9 = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox10_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox10.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox10.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox10.Enabled = True
        p10 = Val(Label10.Text)
    Else
        TextBox10.Enabled = False
        TextBox10.Text = ""
        p10 = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox11_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox11.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox11.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox11.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox11.Enabled = False
        TextBox11.Text = ""
        p1 = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox12_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox12.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox12.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox12.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox12.Enabled = False
        TextBox12.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox13_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox13.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox13.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox13.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox13.Enabled = False
        TextBox13.Text = ""
        p1 = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox14_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox14.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox14.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox14.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox14.Enabled = False
        TextBox14.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox15_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox15.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox15.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox15.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox15.Enabled = False
        TextBox15.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox16_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox16.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox16.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox16.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox16.Enabled = False
        TextBox16.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox17_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox17.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox17.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox17.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox17.Enabled = False
        TextBox17.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox18_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox18.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox18.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox18.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox18.Enabled = False
        TextBox18.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox19_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox19.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox19.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox19.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox19.Enabled = False
        TextBox19.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox20_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox20.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox20.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox20.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox20.Enabled = False
        TextBox20.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox21_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox21.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox21.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox21.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox21.Enabled = False
        TextBox21.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox22_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox22.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox22.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox22.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox22.Enabled = False
        TextBox22.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox23_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox23.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox23.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox23.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox23.Enabled = False
        TextBox23.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox24_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox24.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox24.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox24.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox24.Enabled = False
        TextBox24.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox25_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox25.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox25.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox25.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox25.Enabled = False
        TextBox25.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox26_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox26.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox26.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox26.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox26.Enabled = False
        TextBox26.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox27_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox27.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox27.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox27.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox27.Enabled = False
        TextBox27.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox28_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox28.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox28.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox28.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox28.Enabled = False
        TextBox28.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox29_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox29.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox29.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox29.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox29.Enabled = False
        TextBox29.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox30_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox30.CheckedChanged
    If TextBox30.Enabled = False Then
        TextBox30.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox30.Enabled = False
        TextBox30.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Strg1 = Str(QntCalc(p1, Val(TextBox1.Text)))
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    Strg2 = Str(QntCalc(p2, Val(TextBox2.Text)))
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
    Strg3 = Str(QntCalc(p3, Val(TextBox3.Text)))
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox4_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox4.TextChanged
    Strg4 = Str(QntCalc(p4, Val(TextBox4.Text)))
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox5_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox5.TextChanged
    Strg5 = Str(QntCalc(p5, Val(TextBox5.Text)))
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox6_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox6.TextChanged
    Strg6 = Str(QntCalc(p6, Val(TextBox6.Text)))
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox7_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox7.TextChanged
    Strg7 = Str(QntCalc(p7, Val(TextBox7.Text)))
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox8_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox8.TextChanged
    Strg8 = Str(QntCalc(p8, Val(TextBox8.Text)))
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox9_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox9.TextChanged
    Strg9 = Str(QntCalc(p9, Val(TextBox9.Text)))
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox10_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox10.TextChanged
    Strg10 = Str(QntCalc(p10, Val(TextBox10.Text)))
End Sub

Private Sub MedPrc_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MedPrc.TextChanged
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TotMedPrc = Strg1 + Strg2 + Strg3 + Strg4 + Strg5 + Strg6 + Strg7 + Strg8 + Strg9 + Strg10
    MedPrc.Text = Val(TotMedPrc)
End Sub
End Class
```

Is there a way to shorten this?

Comment: You’ll need arrays here. I suggest you pick up a book on VB programming because this is something so basic that it cannot be well taught in a programming forum.

Comment: that would only shorten the declaration of variables. But, I will try that also

Comment: No, it would shorten the whole code to about a tenth of its current size, since all the rest of the code can be made general by working on the array.

Comment: How to assign values in a array without using loops?

Comment: Why don’t you want to use loops?

Comment: I would like to add different values, not increasing values inside an array, I think when using loops you would only get the value at the loop statement not outside the loop
Am I right?

Comment: I think you’re overcomplicating things massively. Here are the facts: you have N times *identical* code, except for the identifiers. All this code can be folded into one single copy by using arrays instead of separate variables. That’s all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like VB.NET right? In VBA you would write something little bit different. Sample:

```
Option Explicit

Private Strg1  As String
Private p1 As Double

Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
  OnCheckBoxChange Me.TextBox1, Me.Label1, p1
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
  OnTextBoxChanged Me.TextBox1, p1, Strg1
End Sub

Private Sub OnTextBoxChanged(ByRef textBoxControl As Variant, ByRef p As Double, Strg As String)
    Strg = Str(QntCalc(p, Val(textBoxControl.Text)))
End Sub

Private Sub OnCheckBoxChange(ByRef textBoxControl As Variant, ByRef labelControl As Variant, ByRef p As Double)
    If textBoxControl.Enabled = False Then
        textBoxControl.Enabled = True
        p = Val(labelControl.Caption)
    Else
        textBoxControl.Enabled = False
        textBoxControl.Text = ""
        p = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Function QntCalc(ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double) As Double
    QntCalc = x * y
End Function
```

Comment: Maybe you added wrong tag to your question? You wanted VB.NET but added VBA instaed?